# Integrating QTP Script in teamcity

Tags: teamcity, qtp

I'm trying to add QTP script to my team's build steps in Team City.  I've tried searching the web but didn't find anything.

Does anyone know if this possible? If it is possible, how do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not experience specifically with Team City, but wanted to offer this suggestion since you have not had any other feedback yet.  The answer to this question is generally the same for any type of integration... you have to use the QTP API to execute tests and pull back results.  HP provides little direct support for integrating with tools outside of their own, so you have to use their API to build those integrations.  If you also use Quality Center/ALM, you could set up a test set for all of your build validation tests that are executed using the API for QC/ALM instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your build-step to run as command line & specify the script path to run with appropriate parameters. Refer to : http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Command+Line